# Conditional append of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Is it possible to write the following in a more concise way ?

```
if condition:
    a = [1, 7, 2]
else:
    a = [1, 7]
```

I'm looking for a kind of `a = [1, 7, 2 if condition]`

Comment: what is `[1, 7]` ? a predefined constant list? how's that list accumulated?

Comment: Simply check your condition and append `2` to a `[1,7]` list if it is met ...  `a = [1,7]` and `if condition: a.append(2)` should do it. I highly doubt your system is constrained in either memory or runtime for such a short list. A ternary is just a shorthand for that and not much "cleaner"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list addition with a ternary operator `x if cond else y`, which is useful if you don't want to repeat the constant part `[1, 7]`:

```
a = [1, 7] + ([2] if condition else [])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 7, 2] if condition else [1, 7]
```